# User o365 variable in html signature set via disclaimer

Tags: html, exchange-server

I'm trying to use the disclaimer feature in our MS cloud Office 365 service to enforce mandatory approved signatures for everyone.

Due to the consistency, predictability, and graphical aesthetic requirements of the executives, what has been done so far is we have a personalized png file for every single employee with their signature and logo, which looks exactly how they want it to look. This is because using the built in variables for o365 would be less predictable with fonts, word wrap, etc...

So, I have an individualized png file for every single employee of the company that I would like to apply as their signature. I would like to avoid creating a thousand individual transport rules, one for each employee, each pointing to their image file (hosted on http).

The image files are currently named same as the o365 variable UserLogonName. (i.e. FLASTNAME@mycompany.com.png)

I have been able to refer to the signature image, when I set the transport rule individually for a person, with it named like that. But I don't want to do this for every single person in the company.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p></p>

<a href="http://MyCompany.com/">
<img src=http://aws-website-MyCompany.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/signatures/%%UserLogonName%%.png width="398" height="150">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Please note: I don't know what the hell I'm doing in regards to html and javascript, etc... I know the above code is ridiculous. I've tried several variations of setting variables, javascript, etc... so far nothing has worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first: By default, Outlook doesn't automatically download pictures in e-mail messages if the pictures are stored on the Internet. This practice helps to protect your privacy because downloading an Internet picture can alert the sender that your e-mail address is active and that you received the message (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-options-for-downloading-Internet-pictures-3f0f6372-89c1-436d-8a8c-b033a84902ad)).

Blocking pictures can help protect your computer. Microsoft Outlook is configured by default to block automatic picture downloads from the Internet. You can, however, unblock pictures that you think are safe to download.

Advantages of blocking automatic picture downloads include:

- Helping you avoid viewing potentially offensive material (when external content is linked to the message).
- Helping to keep malicious code from damaging the data on your computer.
- Allowing you to decide—especially if you're on a low-bandwidth connection
- whether a particular image warrants the time and bandwidth required for downloading.

(see also [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a))

So your approach will mostly only work internally (if this feature above is configured for your environment correctly). If you send the email to an external party (or a mobile device user) no signature will be shown.

A better option instead of a fileshare would be to embed the image as CSS inline image (via base 64; [here](https://www.base64-image.de/) is a good generator).

It would look like the following:

```css
.googlelogo-color-272x92dp{
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  width:272px;
  height:92px;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<a href="http://MyCompany.com/">
<div class="googlelogo-color-272x92dp">
</div>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Via that way the image is included in the HTML source from the email and not downloaded from the internet.

*P.S: I personally do not like your approach. If a phone number from the remote person is only visible in a picture file, then I couldn´t press on it so that my phone automatically dial the number. I also couldn´t use the "update contact" feature from most smartphones as they couldn´t recognize the content in the email as "contact infos". In our company we offer an HTML generator and everybody is supposed to use it and once entered the name it will generate the correct HTML signature (based on details e.g. phone, name, ... from the Active Directory environment)*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I've been thinking about your comment for a couple of days now. I hope you don't mind answering a couple of follow up questions: 1 - Instead of the entire signature being an image. How about it being a small html table, with the logo in a cell and the user data as actual text with actual links? My only issue with this is the font, which is not a standard Windows font. I can Base64 the logo, but can I can't Base64 the rest can I?

Comment: My second question, which is less important if I do above: Is there a software that can do bulk translation into Base64. I see there are several websites, but they are one at a time. I was hoping for a quicker method, perhaps with a batch process. I have the entire Adobe Suite and I can buy a license for another piece of software if you have a recommendation.